# Fatal error: Call to undefined method MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportListByNextTokenResult::getReportInfo()

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I get this error in MWS API PHP Library when I try to get report list by next token:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportListByNextTokenResult::getReportInfo()

The weird thing is, in the code sample, that is the right function. And also I have checked if the report info exists by using:

```
$response->isSetGetReportListByNextTokenResult()
```

What should I do to get the report info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I open up the library, it turns out their code sample for this API is wrong. The sample uses `getReportInfo()` when it should be `getReportInfoList()`.